# pig is null query

Tags: apache-pig

I am using pig 0.10.
i have an outer bag(relation)

```
grunt>dump e;
(vinyas,(shetty,12),{(12,vinyas),(99,shetty)})
(vas,(shety,12),{(12,vinyas),(33,shetty)})
(fgkyas,(shety,12),{(12,vinyas),(12,shetty)})
(fky,(uhjyt,12),{(,),(,)})

grunt> describe e;
e: {name: chararray,t: (),b: {t: (x: int,y: chararray)}}

grunt> op = filter e by IsEmpty(b) or b is null;
```

Now op does not return anything.I was actually expecting the last tuple of relation e(i.e name with "fky") to be returned.Can some1 plz explain this behavior

Answer (score 0):

[`IsEmpty`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.11.0/org/apache/pig/builtin/IsEmpty.java#IsEmpty.0isEmpty) checks at the size of the `DataBag`, which takes into account empty tuples as well. So you need to specify a more rigorous check.

(And `b` is definitely not `NULL` - so that would not get what you wanted).